# Is "keeper" a property of Lion.prototype

Tags: typescript

I read "generic constraints" section in the TypeScript handbook from its official site(http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#generics-generic-constraints), however, the example the book gave as I pasted below is not ideal

```
class BeeKeeper {
    hasMask: boolean;
}

class ZooKeeper {
    nametag: string; 
}

class Animal {
    numLegs: number;
}

class Bee extends Animal {
    keeper: BeeKeeper;
}

class Lion extends Animal {
    keeper: ZooKeeper;
}

function findKeeper<A extends Animal, K> (a: {new(): A; 
    prototype: {keeper: K}}): K {

    return a.prototype.keeper;
}

findKeeper(Lion).nametag;  // typechecks!
```

I think in findKeeper(Lion) call, the argument given actually is the Lion constructor function as compiled in JS code, and its prototype property is just like an instance of Animal. This fact I get proved from running the code and observed it in Web Developer

[image]

So Am I right that the function findKeeper definition code: "return a.prototype.keeper" is wrong? This error is also got shown to me in the console window with: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nametag' of undefined" when I run the code sample in the browser, since a.prototype.keeper returns undefined.

Could someone explain the purpose of the illustrated example a little bit to help me understand the idea given here and also on how to correct it, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example in the handbook is a great example of how the types can be inferred, i.e. if you pass in a Lion, it knows that `A` is a `Lion` and `K` is a `ZooKeeper`. This is really powerful type inference.

The example is also not a great practical example. Beacuse `Lion` is passed (not an instance of `Lion`), the value of `a.prototype.keeper` has not yet been defined. The code is, otherwise, correct - but just impractical.

This can be overcome in a few ways... but here is one way:

```
class BeeKeeper {
    hasMask: boolean;
}

class ZooKeeper {
    nametag: string; 
}

class Animal {
    keeper: BeeKeeper | ZooKeeper;
    numLegs: number;
}

class Bee extends Animal {
    keeper: BeeKeeper = {
        hasMask: false
    };
}

class Lion extends Animal {
    keeper: ZooKeeper = {
        nametag: 'Icy'
    };
}

function findKeeper<A extends Animal, K> (a: {new(): A; 
    prototype: {keeper: K}}): K {

    var animal: Animal = new a();

    return <any>animal.keeper;
}

var keeperA = findKeeper(Lion);
console.log(keeperA.nametag);  // typechecks!

var keeperB = findKeeper(Bee);
console.log(keeperB.hasMask); // also typechecks!
```

This example still shows off the type-inference, but also has values to demonstrate things fully working.

Comment: Your answer makes sense, I also like to add the "prototype" in (a: {new(): A; 
    prototype: {keeper: K}}) has different meaning from javascript's prototype keyword as in a.prototype.keeper